# Rails - Javascript won't render through link_to, but works fine through normal create action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Encountering a pretty weird bug, and hoping someone can shed some light.

I want Rails to return a random `Tweet` record form the database, so in my `new` method in my `Tweet Controller` I have the following.

```
def new
  @tweet = Tweet.new
  @random_tweet = Tweet.order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

In my *view.html.erb*, I want to direct the `link_to` to whatever the show page `@random_tweet` has, so I have

*view.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @tweet do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :handle%>
  <%= f.submit "Let's Go!", class: "btn btn-lg btn-danger"%>
<% end%>

# returns a random Tweet record
<%=link_to @random_tweet.handle, @random_tweet %>
```

The link works fine, it redirects me to the show page of whatever `@random_tweet` happens to be. The issue is that on each show page, there is a javascript graph that I constructed using d3 and data from tweet.

If I search for a tweet, the graph will show up without any issue. However, if I get to the show page through `@random_tweet` link, it shows everything except the graph.

Any idea what might be happening? Thanks.

If you require my entire controller, it's below. `gon` is just a gem that I use to communicate variables between javascript and controller.

*Tweets Controller*

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
    require 'indico'

    def new
        @tweet = Tweet.new

        #following only works with Postgres
        @random_tweet = Tweet.order("RANDOM()").first

    end

    def create
        @tweet = Tweet.new(tweets_params)

        if Tweet.exists?(:handle => @tweet.handle)
            @original_tweet = Tweet.find_by_handle(@tweet.handle)
            redirect_to @original_tweet
        elsif @tweet.save
            redirect_to @tweet
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def show

        Indico.api_key = ENV["indico_key"]
        @tweet = Tweet.friendly.find(params[:id])
        current_tweets = $client.search("#{@tweet.handle} -rt", result_type: "recent", lang: "en")

        @tweets_array = Tweet.get_tweets_array(current_tweets)

        tweets_array_val_json = Tweet.get_tweets_json(@tweets_array)
        gon.senti_array = tweets_array_val_json

    end

    private

    def tweets_params
        params.require(:tweet).permit(:handle)
    end
end
```

*graph.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = gon.senti_array;


    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 800]);



    d3.select(".chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("div").attr("class", "bar")
      .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('bar') // this needs to change based on how you want to select the generated elements

    for(var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
      var text = divs[i].innerText;

      divs[i].innerHTML = '<a href=#tweet_'+i+' >'+text+'</a>'
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you initializing your javascript graph?

Comment: Hey @AmrNoman, I've updated the question to include the js. thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is related to turbolinks, try removing turbolinks from `application.js` and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi @AmrNoman. Your suggestion works! If you can write up a short answer on what made you think Turbolink was the issue, I'd be more than happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), it helps making your application faster when you visit links by keeping the page alive and only replacing the body.

This sometimes causes problems with javascript events not working as you expect.

You can either turn off turbolinks completely or if you want the speed boost it gives try using its events, so instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

try using:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {});
```

You can see the list of events [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events).